# Elegantly proving $\left(|a|^{p-2}a-|b|^{p-2}b\right)\cdot(a-b)\geq 0 $, for $a, b\in\Bbb{R}$ and $p\geq1$

Tags: calculus, inequality

In a research paper, the following inequality is given:

$$\left(|a|^{p-2}a-|b|^{p-2}b\right)\cdot(a-b)\geq 0 $$

with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $p\geq 1$.

The inequality is actually "elementary" in the sense that if you brutally consider all the cases [$a>0,b<0$], [$a<0,b>0$], [$a,b>0$ with $a<b$ and $a>b$]... and so on, you realize that the inequality holds.

Does someone have an idea of how to prove the inequality in an "elegant" way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that the left factor is undefined if $p < 2$ and $a=0$ or $b=0$.

For all other values you can use
$$
(|a|^{p-2}a-|b|^{p-2}b)\cdot(a-b) = (f(a)-f(b))(a-b)
$$
where
$$
f(x) = \operatorname{sign}(x) |x|^{p-1}
$$
is *increasing* on $\Bbb R$, so that both factors have the same sign, and the product is non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Less direct than Martin's answer, but you can transform using $(a^2+b^2\ge 2ab)$ to:

$\begin{align}(|a|^qa-|b|^qb)(a-b)&=(|a|^qa^2+|b|^qb^2)-ab(|a|^q+|b|^q)\\\\
&\ge(|a|^qa^2+|b|^qb^2)-\tfrac{a^2+b^2}2(|a|^q+|b|^q)\\\\
&\ge \tfrac 12(|a|^q-|b|^q)(a^2-b^2)\\\\&\ge 0
\end{align}$

And since $x^2=|x|^2$ then you can conclude

with the same logic than previously concerning the relative position of $|a|^2,|b|^2$ and $|a|^q,|b|^q$ but easier to grasp than mixed terms with and without absolute value.

If $|a|>|b|$ we multiply two positive terms, else two negative terms.